# Bitmap error when converting it

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmap, emgucv

I'm using EmguCV to create a Histogram, to do this I need a `Bitmap` to create an `Image<Gray, Byte>`.

When I load an image from a file to a Bitmap variable like this:

`Bitmap bmpImg = new Bitmap(filepath);`

`Image<Gray, Byte> emguImg = new Image<Gray, byte>(bmpImg);`

The image creation works fine and I'm able to display the image. However, I need to create this image `Image<Gray, Byte> emguImg` from a structure that comes from my camera.

```
public struct tFrame
{
    public IntPtr AncillaryBuffer;
    public uint AncillaryBufferSize;
    public uint AncillarySize;
    public tBayerPattern BayerPattern;
    public uint BitDepth;
    public tFrameCtx Context;
    public tImageFormat Format;
    public uint FrameCount;
    public uint Height;
    public IntPtr ImageBuffer;
    public uint ImageBufferSize;
    public uint ImageSize;
    public uint RegionX;
    public uint RegionY;
    public tErr Status;
    public uint TimestampHi;
    public uint TimestampLo;
    public uint Width;
}
```

When I create the Bitmap like this:

`Bitmap bmpImg = new Bitmap((int)frame.Width, (int)frame.Height, stride, pxFormat, frame.ImageBuffer);`

I'm able to display this image after converting it to BitmapSource, so I'm assuming that until this point my code is right.

When I try to do this:

`Image<Gray, Byte> emguImg = Image<Gray, byte>(bmpImg);`

I get an error, an exception from `Emgu.CV.CvInvoke`

My question is .. Why on the first case, when I load the image to a `Bitmap` and pass this image to `Image<Gray, Byte>` every thing works fine but when I create the `Bitmap` from my structure and pass it to `Image<Gray, Byte>` I get this exception?

I also tried creating my Image like this:

`Image<Gray, Byte> emguImg = new Image<Gray, byte>((int)frame.Width, (int)frame.Height, stride, frame.ImageBuffer);`

the same error occurs. =\

Help please.

Thank you.

**[edit1]**

The problem was that one *.dll was missing.
If you look the tutorial on EmguCV wiki you'll see that they recomend you to copy a few *.dlls to your debug folder. Well I did that and more, there're 22 *.dlls in emgu's folder, I copied 21 .. and the problem was that missing *.dll
one noob move .. so don't forget to copy those *.dlls

Comment: What exception?  Probably your library only supports certain pixel formats, or requires alignment, or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get an exception on this line:

```
Image<Gray, Byte> emguImg = new Image<Gray, byte>((int)frame.Width, (int)frame.Height, stride, frame.ImageBuffer);
```

What are the values of `frame.Width`, `frame.Height`, and `stride`.  Some systems use negative height or negative stride to differentiate top-down from bottom-up pixel order, and your library may be unhappy with that.

Or it could be an alignment issue.

Set a breakpoint in the debugger and see exactly what you're asking the library to do.

Comment: @Probst: So, what was the problem?  How did you fix it?  Provide information so that this question can help future programmers as well.